# Combining 2 JSON objects when one doesn't exist yet

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
function fetchAPI(string) {
    return fetch(string).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
        return json;
    });
}

try {
   fetchAPI(`https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?key=${apikey}`).then(
       function(result1) {
          delete result1.success;
          delete result1.page;
          delete result1.totalAuctions;
          delete result1.lastUpdated;
          var pages = result1.totalPages;
          delete result1.totalPages;
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
          for (var page = 0; page < pages; page++) {
             fetchAPI(`https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?key=${apikey}&page=${page}`).then(function(results) {
                  delete results.success;
                  delete results.page;
                  delete results.totalAuctions;
                  delete results.lastUpdated;
                  delete results.totalPages;
                  var i = 0;
                  for (i = 0; i < results.auctions.length; i++) {
                      // eslint-disable-next-line quotes
                      if (results.auctions[i].item_name != "Enchanted Book") {
                        delete results.auctions[i];
                      }
                  }
                  fs.appendFile('finalresult.json', JSON.stringify(results), err => {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                  });
                      
             });
          }
       },
   });
} 
catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

In the code, I get info from an API (fetchAPI function), which returns a JSON response. To get all the info from the API, I need to query for each page of the specific endpoint, hence the `for (var page = 0; page < pages; page++)` loop. Then, I need to filter the JSON:

```
for (i = 0; i < results.auctions.length; i++) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line quotes
    if (results.auctions[i].item_name != "Enchanted Book") {
       delete results.auctions[i];
    }
}
```

Then finally, I need to save all the JSON info from each page all into one file. The only issue, is in the future I need to read from that file, and when I do `fs.appendFile('finalresult.json', JSON.stringify(results));`, it doesn't keep JSON format. Is there a way that I can basically make one long JSON file consisting of the API data?

JSON data example ("auctions" will have 1000 items per page, but gets filtered, so the average goes down to 300 per page, so I'll just include an example item):

```json
{
  "success": true,
  "page": 0, // The current page
  "totalPages": 32, // Total amount of pages avaliable
  "totalAuctions": 31267, // Total amount of results in the auction house
  "lastUpdated": 1571065561345, // Unix timestamp in milliseconds of when the data last updated in the API
  "auctions": [ // The auctions themselves
    {
      "uuid": "bc581ce675e94a0c88ac9deae06090f0",
      "auctioneer": "96a7c06732f54c1382ab6a2515dbb960",
      "profile_id": "96a7c06732f54c1382ab6a2515dbb960",
      "coop": [
        "96a7c06732f54c1382ab6a2515dbb960"
      ],
      "start": 1571049581232,
      "end": 1571071181232,
      "item_name": "Magical Mushroom Soup",
      "item_lore": "§7Consuming this Magical Mushroom\n§7Soup on your private island\n§7allows the player to fly for §a2\n§aminutes§7. Leaving the private\n§7island will remove the effect!\n\n§a§lUNCOMMON",
      "extra": "Magical Mushroom Soup Mushroom Soup",
      "category": "consumables",
      "tier": "UNCOMMON",
      "starting_bid": 256,
      "item_bytes": "...",
      "claimed": false,
      "claimed_bidders": [],
      "highest_bid_amount": 256,
      "bids": [
        {
          "auction_id": "bc581ce675e94a0c88ac9deae06090f0",
          "bidder": "70aafcc6764b45ff80e60226193a0784",
          "profile_id": "70aafcc6764b45ff80e60226193a0784",
          "amount": 256,
          "timestamp": 1571065921089
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Everything except "auctions" is removed from the JSON by the time I need to merge it

Comment: JSON inside the code is just and object. Of course you can add fields there. But you should only call `stringify` once in the end. So please show us an examples of JSON you are trying to merge together.

Comment: Will do, give me a second while I get that and update the post.

Comment: @Anton I have added an example of the JSON. Basically, both JSONs are the same format, and I've written some code to remove everything except "auctions". Other than that, the JSONs are almost the exact same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, man. I've been tired today and forgot about async nature of your code.

Here is totally working example (even without apiKey). You can run it:

```js
//const originalUrl = `https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?key=${apikey}`;
const originalUrl = `https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?rnd=1`;
const nameToSearch = 'Enchanted Book';

function showLoaded(count, total) {
  const el = document.getElementById('loader');
  if (count) el.innerText = '' + count + ' of ' + total;
  else el.innerText = 'ALL';
}

function fetchAPI(string) {
  return fetch(string)
   .then(response => response.json());
}

function getAuctionsFromPage(page, totalPages) {
  return fetchAPI(originalUrl + `&page=${page}`)
    .then(result => {
      loaded++;
      showLoaded(loaded, totalPages);
      return result.auctions
    })
    .then(auctions => auctions.filter(auction => auction.item_name == nameToSearch));
}

let loaded = 0;

function collectData(totalPages) {
  const allPages = [];
  loaded = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < totalPages; i++) {
    allPages.push(getAuctionsFromPage(i, totalPages));
  }
  return Promise.all(allPages)
    .then(auctions => auctions.flat(1))
    .then(auctions => {
      showLoaded();
      return {
        auctions
      }
    });
}

function saveToFile(data) {
  // Put data to file
  fs.appendFile('finalresult.json', JSON.stringify(data), err => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });
}

function saveToConsole(data) {
  const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
  //console.log(jsonData);
  document.getElementById('console').innerHTML = 'We found ' + data.auctions.length + ' items named ' + nameToSearch + '<br/>Data size is ' + jsonData.length + ' bytes';
}

try {
  document.getElementById('loader').innerText = 'Getting total pages...';
  fetchAPI(originalUrl)
    .then(result => result.totalPages)
    .then(totalPages => collectData(totalPages))
    .then(data => saveToConsole(data));
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

```html
<div>Loaded: <span id="loader">0</span></div>
<div id="console"></div>
```

Note: to save data to file you need to change `.then(data => saveToConsole(data))` to `.then(data => saveToFile(data))`

Comment: Alright, thank you for that. I believe I was able to translate that into node.js (which was tagged in the question, but it's fine if you missed it due to you being tired.) The only thing I was getting errors about (because I'm using node.js, not browser javascript) was`const el = jsdom.document.getElementById('loader');` in the showLoaded function. The error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined` was thrown to console, which I'm assuming is because it's being run in node.js. Any solutions you can give for that? Thank you for all your assistance by the way!

Comment: @DeltaCodes oh, come on =) you do not need any of `getElementById` (not working in node). I added them just for testing. So you can remove: `showLoaded` function, `saveToConsole` function, this two lines: `loaded++; showLoaded(loaded, totalPages);`, this line: `let loaded = 0;`, this `loaded = 0;`  and this: `showLoaded();` and finally this: `document.getElementById('loader').innerText = 'Getting total pages...';`

Comment: You are a LIFESAVER! Thank you very much!